# Error trying to create an calculator app using Javascript Function

Tags: javascript, function, conditional-statements

I was trying to make a function that only accepts numbers and some special characters in a text field, but it is accepting any key that I press, even though it is not in the condition that I imposed, I am calling the function via onkeydown in an html input that i called id "resultado"

`

```
const numPress = (evt) =>{
    let charCode = evt.keyCode || evt.which;
    let charStr = String.fromCharCode(charCode);
    let allowedKeys = ["+", "-", "*", "/"]
    let currentValue = document.getElementById('resultado').value
    if (evt.keyCode === 8)
    {
        currentValue = currentValue.slice(0,-1);
        console.log('Apagou!')    
    } 
    else if (!isNaN(parseInt(charStr) || allowedKeys.includes(charStr) )) 
    {
        console.log(currentValue)
        currentValue += charStr
    } else{
    currentValue = 'Error'
    }
}
```

`
i was expecting it would only accept numbers and the keys listed in my allowedKeys (+, -, /, *) but it is accepting any key

Answer (score 0):

You misplaced the brackets in the second condition. It should be:

```js
else if (!isNaN(parseInt(charStr)) || allowedKeys.includes(charStr))
```

You are currently passing `parseInt(charStr) || allowedKeys.includes(charStr)` as the argument to `isNaN`.

Comment: thanks for that, lol i forgot to close the brackets, but my function is still accepting every key pressed

Comment: @GabrielBrito You can use `evt.preventDefault()` in the `else` branch.